# Rolling avg with dynamic preceding rows Snowflake SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This is a sample of my data and what I want to calculate is in the rightmost column using the other columns:

| DATE | Item | Brand | Cycle_length | Brand_Avg_Cycle_Length_3_Weeks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13/09/2023 | 123 | Apple | 6 |  |
| 13/09/2023 | 500 | Apple | 5 |  |
| 20/09/2023 | 123 | Apple | **6** |  |
| 20/09/2023 | 500 | Apple | **5** |  |
| 27/09/2023 | 123 | Apple | **6** | 5.333333 |
| 27/09/2023 | 500 | Apple | **4** | 5.333333 |
| 04/10/2023 | 123 | Apple | **6** | **5.167777** |
| 04/10/2023 | 500 | Apple | **4** | **5.167777** |
| 13/09/2023 | 325 | Samsung | 7 |  |
| 13/09/2023 | 862 | Samsung | 3 |  |
| 13/09/2023 | 455 | Samsung | 5 |  |
| 20/09/2023 | 325 | Samsung | **7** |  |
| 20/09/2023 | 862 | Samsung | **3** |  |
| 27/09/2023 | 455 | Samsung | **5** |  |
| 04/10/2023 | 325 | Samsung | **7** | 5.333333 |
| 27/09/2023 | 862 | Samsung | **4** | 5.333333 |
| 04/10/2023 | 455 | Samsung | **7** | 5.333333 |
| 11/10/2023 | 325 | Samsung | **7** | **5.666667** |
| 04/10/2023 | 862 | Samsung | **4** | **5.666667** |
| 11/10/2023 | 455 | Samsung | **7** | **5.666667** |

The rightmost column is taking all the items in a brand and looking back 3 weeks including current (so 3 rows for each item) and calculating the average of the cycle length column. This is what I'm unable to calculate in Snowflake.

The bold values in the Cycle_length column are being used to calculate the bold values in the Brand_avg_cycle_length_3_weeks column. This is calculated for each item separately.

I've tried a number of things including partition by (with preceding) function but no luck. The blocker is that preceding only looks back a certain number of rows whereas I want to look back: number of weeks multiplied by number of items in brand rows back.

```
SELECT report_date
,item_cd
,recent_cycle_length
,brand_name
,max(report_date) as latestdate
,avg(recent_cycle_length) over 
    (partition by brand_name 
     order by report_date 
     rows between 11 preceding and current row) AS BRAND_AVG_CYCLE_LENGTH_LAST_12_WEEKS
FROM table
group by recent_cycle_length, brand_name, report_Date,item_cd
;
```

Comment: Apologies about the images - I don't have 10 reputation points so cannot add images without attaching them as above.

Comment: Please don’t add anything as images, even if you could. Add information as editable text - formatted appropriately

Comment: @NickW have corrected, thanks for mentioning

Comment: Can you also explain why you are calculating this value for some rows and not others - what are the rules determining this?

Comment: I am not calculating it for the first two dates because we can't go back three weeks for those, the dates only start from 13/09/2023 for this data sample

Comment: Please explain what is the mathematical logic for your final numbers?

Comment: (Samsung, 2023-10-04) you have two different averages: 5.333 and 5.667, why?

Comment: Hey  @tinazmu that's because it's a rolling window on the cycle length column (window of length: three multiplied by the number of items)

Comment: @TejaGoudKandula hopefully my comment to tinazmu helped and Andrei's answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of Snowflake doesn't support a `RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL`, the solution uses the trick from the KB "[How to rewrite a `RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL` query in Snowflake](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-rewrite-a-RANGE-BETWEEN-INTERVAL-query-in-Snowflake)".

```
drop table if exists "table";

create temporary table "table" (
  report_date date,
  Item number(5),
  Brand_name varchar(30),
  Cycle_length number(3)
);

insert into "table" values
  ('2023-09-13', 123, 'Apple', 6),
  ('2023-09-13', 500, 'Apple', 5),
  ('2023-09-20', 123, 'Apple', 6),
  ('2023-09-20', 500, 'Apple', 5),
  ('2023-09-27', 123, 'Apple', 6),
  ('2023-09-27', 500, 'Apple', 4),
  ('2023-10-04', 123, 'Apple', 6),
  ('2023-10-04', 500, 'Apple', 4),
  ('2023-09-13', 325, 'Samsung', 7),
  ('2023-09-13', 862, 'Samsung', 3),
  ('2023-09-13', 455, 'Samsung', 5),
  ('2023-09-20', 325, 'Samsung', 7),
  ('2023-09-20', 862, 'Samsung', 3),
  ('2023-09-27', 455, 'Samsung', 5),
  ('2023-10-04', 325, 'Samsung', 7),
  ('2023-09-27', 862, 'Samsung', 4),
  ('2023-10-04', 455, 'Samsung', 7),
  ('2023-10-11', 325, 'Samsung', 7),
  ('2023-10-04', 862, 'Samsung', 4),
  ('2023-10-11', 455, 'Samsung', 7);

select
  a.*,
  case datediff(week, min(b.report_date), max(b.report_date))
    when 2 then avg(b.Cycle_length)
  end as "3_weeks_avg"
from "table" as a
join "table" as b
  on b.Brand_name = a.Brand_name and
     b.report_date between a.report_date - interval '2 weeks' and
                           a.report_date
group by a.report_date, a.Item, a.Brand_name, a.Cycle_length
order by a.Brand_name, a.report_date;
```

Result:

```
+-------------+------+------------+--------------+-------------+
| REPORT_DATE | ITEM | BRAND_NAME | CYCLE_LENGTH | 3_weeks_avg |
+-------------+------+------------+--------------+-------------+
| 2023-09-13  |  500 | Apple      |            5 |             |
| 2023-09-13  |  123 | Apple      |            6 |             |
| 2023-09-20  |  123 | Apple      |            6 |             |
| 2023-09-20  |  500 | Apple      |            5 |             |
| 2023-09-27  |  123 | Apple      |            6 | 5.333333    |
| 2023-09-27  |  500 | Apple      |            4 | 5.333333    |
| 2023-10-04  |  123 | Apple      |            6 | 5.166667    |
| 2023-10-04  |  500 | Apple      |            4 | 5.166667    |
| 2023-09-13  |  862 | Samsung    |            3 |             |
| 2023-09-13  |  455 | Samsung    |            5 |             |
| 2023-09-13  |  325 | Samsung    |            7 |             |
| 2023-09-20  |  325 | Samsung    |            7 |             |
| 2023-09-20  |  862 | Samsung    |            3 |             |
| 2023-09-27  |  455 | Samsung    |            5 | 4.857143    |
| 2023-09-27  |  862 | Samsung    |            4 | 4.857143    |
| 2023-10-04  |  325 | Samsung    |            7 | 5.285714    |
| 2023-10-04  |  455 | Samsung    |            7 | 5.285714    |
| 2023-10-04  |  862 | Samsung    |            4 | 5.285714    |
| 2023-10-11  |  325 | Samsung    |            7 | 5.857143    |
| 2023-10-11  |  455 | Samsung    |            7 | 5.857143    |
+-------------+------+------------+--------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Hi Andrei, thanks very much for this. I did end up using a self join and that did the trick!